# save data from a webpage in an xml document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, save, html

I made a webpage using c# asp.net. It has various text fields and dropdown lists and a radio button. Now i want to save the data into an xml file. and i'm not really able to understand on how to go about it.

The various attributes in my page are TEXTBOX: GInfo; LNo; Org; UName; SType; Ver; MeapSupp; MaxUser; MaxMach; MachIP; MachMac; UqID

DROPDOWNLIST: LType

RADIO BUTTON: MeapSupp

I'm new to XML and asp.net and c#. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code - based on `XmlTextWriter  class`

```
                XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("yourpath", null);
                // Opens the document
                textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

textWriter.WriteStartElement("root");
textWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "urn:1");

                // Write comments
                textWriter.WriteComment("First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example");

textWriter.WriteEndElement();


                // Ends the document.
                textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                // close writer
                textWriter.Close();
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx

You can also use LINQ To XML

```
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment("This is a test"),
        new XElement("root")
    );

    var root = doc.CreateElement("Test");
    ....
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: i tried making the same but it's giving me this error:XML document must have a top level element. Error processing resource 'file:///D:/DEV/Gen_Lic.xml'.

Comment: you create root with XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment("This is a test"),
        new XElement("root")
    );

Comment: i created my xml file using this: `XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("D:\\DEV\\Gen_Lic.xml");`

Comment: Is there anyway apart from linq?

Comment: it's still giving me the same error. Is it possible that the nodes aren't being created? Because I'm basically generating a new xml file using my c# code.